# Encrypting zip files with a password based on Zip 2.0 encryption

Tags: java, encryption, zip, password-protection

I am trying to zip and encrypt files in Java (1.6) with a password based on the earlier Zip 2.0 encryption. I have used AES 256 bit encrytpion to encrypt zip files with password and have successfully been able to do so.

Though AES is a stronger and a more secure encryption standard, i need to find a standard that is more widely supported across all zip clients so that the users have a higher success rates opening the password protected zip files. So i was looking for some Zip 2.0 based encryption to encrypt my files. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: To anyone reading this question now (end of 2013ish): Don't use the builtin ZIP encryption, it's horrendously insecure and can be cracked in an hour by any half-decent programmer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Zip4j, a pure java library to handle zip file. It supports encryption/decryption of PKWare and AES encryption methods.

http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/

Key features:

- Create, Add, Extract, Update, Remove files from a Zip file
- Read/Write password protected Zip files
- Supports AES 128/256 Encryption
- Supports Standard Zip Encryption
- Supports Zip64 format
- Supports Store (No Compression) and Deflate compression method
- Create or extract files from Split Zip files (Ex: z01, z02,...zip)
- Supports Unicode file names
- Progress Monitor

License:

- Zip4j is released under Apache License, Version 2.0

Answer (score -1):

I think that nearly all zip-clients do support the WinZip-AES-encryption. As WinZip is far more spread than the original pkzip, it's encryption has become the de-facto standard.
Do you have a specific client which does not support the aes-encryption?

Comment: Hi Sven,
   I've had complaints from 7-zip v4.65 on Windows and unzip utility on Linux so far.
I'm not sure if going back to an older encryption standard is a good idea, but i thought I could use a standard that ensures a good level of success on greater number of zip clients. 

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it was v4.65 for 7-zip? v4.64 fixed a bug in the decryption of AES-encrypted zip-files:
http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt

Comment: Actually, AES encryption is not ubiquitously supported, even now. For example, J2SE itself does not support WinZip AES encryption.  Nor does sharpziplib, I think.  WinZip AES is probably the most widely supported *strong* encryption mechanism for zip files, but zip2.0 encryption is much more widely supported than Winzip AES.